# ITEAD PN532 on Pi 3 with libnfc

Tags: gpio, raspbian-jessie, pi-3, rfid, nfc

For the past weeks I have been trying to get the ITEAD PN532 NFC board working on a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian Jessie (2016-03-18) using `libnfc`.

Here's some [info on the board itself](http://wiki.iteadstudio.com/ITEAD_PN532_NFC_MODULE). It has two switches to set the mode between UART, SPI or IIC.

Before we start, here's my `lsmod` for reference.
In short, Serial disabled, SPI and I2C enabled with kernel modules loaded.

```
brcmfmac              177635  0
joydev                  9024  0
brcmutil                5501  1 brcmfmac
cfg80211              407580  1 brcmfmac
evdev                  10278  4
rfkill                 16036  2 cfg80211
i2c_bcm2708             4920  0
bcm2835_gpiomem         2860  0
bcm2835_rng             1763  0
snd_bcm2835            19802  3
spi_bcm2835             7074  0
snd_pcm                73474  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_timer              18848  1 snd_pcm
snd                    50779  9 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm
uio_pdrv_genirq         2944  0
uio                     7753  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
i2c_dev                 5671  0
fuse                   80694  3
ipv6                  338660  32
```

This is what's uncommented in `/boot/config.txt`

```
disable_overscan=1

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c=on
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=audio=on
dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt
```

Here's what I've tried:

- **I2C (device tree disabled)**
  Considered a REALLY BAD IDEA but I *did* get the board working via I2C. Was advised against it and to pursue device tree enabled solution, so all following attempts have DT enabled again.
- **UART**

  - SET0 L / SET1 L
  - `/etc/nfc/libnfc.conf`

```
allow_autoscan = true
allow_intrusive_scan = false
device.name = "ITEAD PN532"
device.connstring = "pn532_uart:/dev/serial0"
```

but also

```
allow_autoscan = true
allow_intrusive_scan = false
device.name = "ITEAD PN532"
device.connstring = "pn532_uart:/dev/ttyS0"
```

Result:

> ~$ nfc-list 
>   nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
> error   libnfc.driver.pn532_uart
>   pn53x_check_communication 
> error nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC
>   device: pn532_uart:/dev/serial0

I also tried with and without the `dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt`, this seems to do nothing.

- **I2C**

  - SET0 H / SET1 L
  - `/etc/nfc/libnfc.conf`

```
allow_autoscan = true
allow_intrusive_scan = false
device.name = "ITEAD PN532"
device.connstring = "pn532_i2c:/dev/i2c-1"
```

Result:

> ~$ nfc-list
>   nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1 
> error   libnfc.bus.i2c  Error: wrote only -1 bytes (10 expected).
>   error   libnfc.driver.pn532_i2c
>   Unable to transmit data. (TX) pn53x_check_communication: Input /
>   Output Error 
>   error   libnfc.bus.i2c  Error: wrote only -1 bytes (10
>   expected). 
> error   libnfc.driver.pn532_i2c Unable to transmit data.
>   (TX) nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: pn532_i2c:/dev/i2c-1

`i2cdetect -y 1` result is empty.

- **SPI**

  - SET0 L / SET1 H
  - `/etc/nfc/libnfc.conf`

```
allow_autoscan = true
allow_intrusive_scan = false
device.name = "ITEAD PN532"
device.connstring = "pn532_uart:/dev/spidev0.0:500000"
```

Result:

> ~ $ nfc-list 
>   nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
>   error libnfc.driver.pn532_spi Unable to wait for SPI data. (RX)
>   pn53x_check_communication: Timeout
>   error libnfc.driver.pn532_spi Unable to wait for SPI data. (RX)
>   nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC
>   device: pn532_spi:/dev/spidev0.0:500000

I've followed whatever I found in terms of wiring schemes for UART, SPI and I2C in whatever limited, disparate and usually downright wrong information I could puzzle together online but it's possible that I've incorrectly wired the device at some point using the individual jumper wires. That's why I've tried all of the above with a downgrade GPIO flat cable as well but that didn't make a difference.

And with that, I'm at the end of my wits.

Comment: Make sure you don't have `getty` running on `/dev/ttyS0`. This would not explain, of course, why you can't get the board running under SPI. You haven't explained why you need to disable the device tree to use I2C. My I2C devices work just fine with DT enabled!

Comment: Did you follow [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=78966) exactly?

Comment: If I knew why I can only get the board to work with DT disabled, I would probably be able to figure out how to make it work with DT enabled as well.

Comment: @user1147688 yes I did and there are several reasons why this can't be followed to the letter for a Pi 3 and/or Raspbian Jessie.
First of all, there's no more /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf and the spi-bcm2708 has been replaced with another version.
Second, the old Pi 1 didn't have a device tree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found a solution although I take no credit for it:

"

Turns out the Raspberry Pi 3 uses the first serial port for its integrated Bluetooth!  There are several ways to get around the problem, knowing this. For now and for my purposes, simply disabling bluetooth did the trick: 
add

```
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
```

to `/boot/config.txt`
and then `sudo systemctl disable hciuart` to disable to the bluetooth service.
Reboot and NFC through /dev/ttyAMA0 works again!

"

Original link [here](http://forums.nfc-tools.org/topic/1486/solvedlibnfc-works-on-raspberry-pi-2-doesnt-work-on-raspberry-pi-3/).

This works flawlessly.

Comment: Another update to this: I was unable to get this working at all using serial or i2c, but *was* able to get it working with SPI but had to turn down the frequency. 500khz doesn't work, but 280khz does (so `device.connstring = "pn532_uart:/dev/spidev0.0:280000"`)

Comment: I have the same problem as this question but dtoverlay is already set to mentiioned value. I tried UART, SPI , I2C but none of them worked... Have you any idea? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that I have a similar question to yours and I solved mine by looking at this information here:
[Serial port in RPI 3](http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection#Preventing_Linux_using_the_serial_port)

It is now referenced as ttyS0. I can test my program to run fine when I change my device reference from ttyAMA0 to ttyS0. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I hadn't come across this yet so I'll be sure to try it tonight!

Comment: No joy. Tried this, tried the overlay to disable bt, no response over UART, it doesn't even see an NFC device. I am using the ITEAD PN521 though, not the AdaFruit board. Thanks anyway. The quest continues...